# create jquery array to use as options

Tags: jquery, select

I'm sure this is really simple, but I can't seem to get it working. I have a "time" select list, which has a number as "rel" attached to each option. If the user changes the time selected, I want a new list of options to display depending on what is selected. Does that make sense?

Here's my first select:

```
<select name="time" id="time">
  <option value="7:00am" rel="10">7:00am</option>
  <option value="12:30pm" rel="16">12:30pm</option>
</select>
```

If the user selects 7:00am, I want a new option list (using jquery) to give options from 1 - 10. Like this:

```
<select name="quantity" id="quantity">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  ............................
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Here's what I have so far...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  jQuery("#time").change(function(){
    var positions = jQuery("#time :selected").attr("rel"); //this grabs the rel from time

    //this is where it should create a list of options to append(??) to the select list.

    jQuery("#showQuantity").show(); //this shows the hidden field for quantity
  });
</script>
```

I hope it makes sense, but I'm stuck on it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand a couple of parts. Does there need to be a different list of options for each `rel` value?  How does the rel affect the options available? Most likely there are several ways ways to accomplish what you're looking to do.

Comment: The rel for the times change, but that's done earlier on in the code.. So it's variable.

There should only be one "quantity" select list, with the numbers from 1 to (whatever the selected rel value is) if that makes sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the code you can use for adding options.

```
    $("#quantity").empty();//Clear options if there are any already existing ones.

    for( i=1; i<= positions; i++ )
    {

        $("#quantity").append($("<option value="+i+">"+ i+"</option>") );

    }
```

Comment: I am little bit confuse about requirement but there is one more question from my side. The question is that, is it possible to add values in #quantity select from database in PHP and JSP?

Comment: Thanks Sharath for your help, worked great!

@Param I can't grab it from the database as the positions change, depending on a few different things in the database, and also what the user selects on the form.